# Dealing with multiple conditionals in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm making a MIPS program that reads and solves kakuro puzzles. At the moment it can read and print the puzzle out, but I have been having some issues adding in error checking. There are a lot of checks I have to do, and for some reason the program both doesn't terminate as it should. If the input contains a value that is not legal (legal values would be: 0, or individual clues in the range 1-45, or an individual "block" clue of 99), then your program must print the following error message and the program must terminate. Some examples of legal input:

```
9999 blocking across and down clues
0799 across clue of 7, blocking down clue
9942 blocking across clue, down clue of 42
1208 across clue of 12, down clue of 8
```

So, this is what I came up with in C:

```
acrossClue = num / 100;
downClue = num % 100;
if(num != 0 && (1 > acrossClue || 45 < acrossClue || acrossClue != 99) 
|| (1 > downClue || 45 < downClue || downClue != 99)) {
    printf("Illegal input value, Cross sums terminating\n");
    return 1;
}
```

Below is the code for main and the read function I made. Any suggestions for transferring the conditionals and logic to MIPS? It doesn't work currently, because even if it gets incorrect input it still runs (readPuzzle returns 1 despite terminating early) and it messes up the puzzle even if the input is correct. My thoughts were if the input isn't any of the values checked it can't be valid, but I'm guessing somewhere along the line I'm not checking properly and it's messing everything up. Does anyone notice anything off with any of the checking I do in readPuzzle?

```
#
# Name:         MAIN PROGRAM
# Description:  Main logic for the program.
#
#               The program reads these values from standard input:
#               1) an integer representing the size of the puzzle
#               2) integers representing values for each cell for the puzzle
#
#               If the dimensions of the board and values of the cells are
#               valid, the program then displays the initial puzzle, attempts
#               to solve it, and displays the solution if there is one.

    .text                           # this is program code
    .align 2                        # instructions must be on word boundaries
    .globl main                     # main is a global label

main:

    # Allocate stack frame

    addi    $sp, $sp,-FRAMESIZE_40
    sw      $ra, 32($sp)
    sw      $s7, 28($sp)
    sw      $s6, 24($sp)
    sw      $s5, 20($sp)
    sw      $s4, 16($sp)
    sw      $s3, 12($sp)
    sw      $s2, 8($sp)
    sw      $s1, 4($sp)
    sw      $s0, 0($sp)

    la      $t0, size

    li      $v0, READ_INT
    syscall
    move    $s0, $v0            # save size n

    blt     $s0, MIN_SIZE, size_error
    bgt     $s0, MAX_SIZE, size_error

    sw      $v0, 0($t0)

    move    $a0, $s0
    jal     readPuzzle

    move    $t7, $v0

    li      $v0, PRINT_INT
    move    $a0, $t7
    syscall

    beq     $v0, $zero, main_done

    la      $s1, puzzle

    li      $v0, PRINT_STRING
    la      $a0, newline
    syscall

    li      $v0, PRINT_STRING
    la      $a0, banner_border
    syscall

    li      $v0, PRINT_STRING
    la      $a0, banner_mid
    syscall

    li      $v0, PRINT_STRING
    la      $a0, banner_border
    syscall

    li      $v0, PRINT_STRING
    la      $a0, newline
    syscall

    li      $v0, PRINT_STRING
    la      $a0, initial
    syscall

    move    $a0, $s0
    move    $a1, $s1
    jal     printPuzzle

    li      $v0, PRINT_STRING
    la      $a0, final
    syscall

    move    $a0, $s0
    move    $a1, $s1
    jal     printPuzzle

    j       main_done

size_error:

    li      $v0, PRINT_STRING
    la      $a0, invalid_size
    syscall

    j       main_done

main_done:

    # Restore stack frame

    lw      $ra, 32($sp)
    lw      $s7, 28($sp)
    lw      $s6, 24($sp)
    lw      $s5, 20($sp)
    lw      $s4, 16($sp)
    lw      $s3, 12($sp)
    lw      $s2, 8($sp)
    lw      $s1, 4($sp)
    lw      $s0, 0($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, FRAMESIZE_40
    jr      $ra

# Name:         readPuzzle
#
# Description:  Reads in the puzzle from a file or stdin.
#
# Arguments:    a0      The size n
#
# Returns:      1 if the read was successful, otherwise 0
#

readPuzzle:

    addi    $sp, $sp, -FRAMESIZE_40
    sw      $ra, 32($sp)
    sw      $s7, 28($sp)
    sw      $s6, 24($sp)
    sw      $s5, 20($sp)
    sw      $s4, 16($sp)
    sw      $s3, 12($sp)
    sw      $s2, 8($sp)
    sw      $s1, 4($sp)
    sw      $s0, 0($sp)

    move    $s0, $a0

    mul     $s1, $s0, $s0       # get n * n
    li      $s2, 0
    la      $s3, puzzle
    li      $s4, 4
    li      $s5, 0              # row = 0
    li      $s6, 0              # col = 0
    mul     $s1, $s1, $s4       # get (n * n) * 4 bytes
    li      $t1, 100

    j       read_loop

read_loop:

    beq     $s2, $s1, read_done

    beq     $s5, $s1, reset

    li      $v0, READ_INT
    syscall
    move    $s7, $v0

    beq     $s7, $zero, continue

    div     $s7, $t1

    mflo    $t2                 # acrossClue = num / 100
    mfhi    $t3                 # downClue = num % 100

    seq     $t4, $t2, Block_Value
    seq     $t5, $t3, Block_Value

    seq     $t6, $t4, $t5
    bne     $t6, $zero, continue

    li      $t6, MIN_CLUE   # minimum value = 2
    li      $t7, MAX_CLUE   # maximum value = 45

    slt     $t4, $t2, $t6       # 1 if acrossClue < 2, otherwise 0
    slt     $t5, $t7, $t2       # 1 if acrossClue > 45, otherwise 0
    bne     $t4, $zero, illegal_input
    bne     $t5, $zero, illegal_input

    slt     $t4, $t3, $t6       # 1 if downClue < 2, otherwise 0
    slt     $t5, $t7, $t3       # 1 if downClue > 45, otherwise 0
    bne     $t4, $zero, illegal_input
    bne     $t5, $zero, illegal_input

    j       continue

continue:

    move    $a0, $s5
    move    $a1, $s6
    move    $a2, $s7
    jal     setElement

    addi    $s6, $s6, 1
    addi    $s2, $s2, 4
    j       read_loop

reset:

    addi    $s5, $s5, 1
    li      $s6, 0

illegal_input:

    li      $v0, PRINT_STRING
    la      $a0, invalid_input
    syscall

    li      $v0, 0

    j       read_done

read_done:

    li      $v0, 1

    lw      $ra, 32($sp)
    lw      $s7, 28($sp)
    lw      $s6, 24($sp)
    lw      $s5, 20($sp)
    lw      $s4, 16($sp)
    lw      $s3, 12($sp)
    lw      $s2, 8($sp)
    lw      $s1, 4($sp)
    lw      $s0, 0($sp)
    addi    $sp, $sp, FRAMESIZE_40
    jr      $ra
```

Edit: I got it so that it correctly knows when the input is valid or invalid, but it still doesn't terminate when there's an invalid input value.

Comment: I haven't done MIPS assembler in years, but should not you insert some delay slots after each branch instruction? Suppose, this depends on the exact version of the MIPS core you're targeting, but you haven't specified this in the question.

Comment: @oakad I have never heard of that before. I looked it up though and I am confused as to how I got this far without using them. Do you have any idea what they look like in MIPS? I'll try to find an example online in the meantime.

Comment: An instruction immediately following the branch must not be a branch. That's it. Start with putting a NOP after each branch - if it works, try to optimize further.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180412-00/?p=98495

Comment: @oakad When you say works, do you mean the logic for the branches? Because I think that's still off. If I give it valid input it sees it as invalid (and continues to print the empty puzzle) and valid when it should be invalid (does the same).

Comment: Consider drawing a flow chart for your program. Then convert it to assembly box by box. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart

Comment: @oakad I drew up a flowchart and think I have a better understanding of how to approach the problem. I will now do over the conditionals and will also keep the delay slots in mind as well. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @oakad: The SPIM and MARS simulators for MIPS by default simulate a MIPS *without* branch delay slots.  There's an option you can uncheck that will make them emulate a normal MIPS with branch delay slots (which yes it does have: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_slot#Branch_delay_slots).    Most MIPS questions on Stack Overflow are from students using MARS/SPIM, with the simplified architecture (and "system calls" that read or print integers), not from people learning or programming Linux or IRIX or whatever embedded OS on real MIPS.